# I need to implement a timer in my SpriteKit Game?

Tags: swift, timer, sprite

In my Game I need to implement a 30 Second timer that starts when I tap on 
the screen so that if the player hasn't reached the objective before the timer reaches 0 its game over.

I can't figure out how to make the timer Count down to Zero after i touch the screen , it just stays at 30 sec . I tried implementing a NStimer but I'm aware you would have to add a PAUSE feature which i don't want ,plus the NStimer counts down before I touch the screen which i also don't want.

This is my code so far:

```
    var TimerNode: Int = 30
    var  TimerLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "STHeitJ-Medium")

    TimerLabel.text = "\(TimerNode)"
    TimerLabel.fontSize = 40
    TimerLabel.position.x = size.width / 2
    TimerLabel.position.y = size.height / 8.5
    TimerLabel.zPosition = 3.00
    TimerLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    addChild(TimerLabel)
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can't figure out how to make the timer Count down to Zero after i touch the screen , it just stays at 30 sec . I tried implementing a NStimer but I'm aware you would have to add a PAUSE feature which i don't want ,plus the NStimer counts down before I touch the screen which i also don't want..please help  @AnkurAggarwal

Comment: Moved OPs comment into the question to make it a question.

Comment: OPs ?? i dont understand ??

Comment: @PaulBalestier OP means ["Original Poster"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253162/what-is-an-op-when-referring-to-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 0):

```
self.addChild(myLabel)
```

You can implement a timer like this:

```
//Timer that updates Label:

myLabel.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run {
            TimerNode -= 1
            TimerLabel.text = "\(TimerNode)"

            if TimerNode <= 0 {

                 //Game Over code
            }
            },SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)])))
```

---

Old:

```
//Run when clicked: 
var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(30)
var run = SKAction.runBlock {
    //Game Over
}
self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, run]))
```

Comment: would I input this code under the touchesBegan method ?? or input the code under its own Function ?

Comment: put it in the touches began method.

Comment: The console is telling me that its working however i can't see it in the screen is there something else i need to do ? @Entitize

Comment: just to clear confusion , i need an actually timer attached to a label on the screen to countdown to zero when i touch the screen

Comment: ok i updated the code for that purpose. look at the new answer

Comment: I tried to implement this code . i got an error saying "Cannot call value of non-function type 'SKAction'   and it points to the first parentheses after self.run @Entitize

Comment: I updated the code you have to do myLabel.run(...). and change the other variable names yourself.

Comment: i entered the edited code and an error saying " Use of unresolved identifier "myLabel"   . i know this is because i didn't resolve it under GameScene but what do i resolve it as ??? and again will the code be under touches began ??? just by looking at the code i can't tell what "my label is equal too and how it is connected to the SKAction . @Entitize

Comment: Sorry to bother but i have another issue with the code ,, it works but it seems like every time i touch the screen after the first time the timer skips ahead , how can i fix this @Entitize

Comment: Add a boolean variable to keep track of the game state.  Don't run the code if the screen has already been touched and the game is started.  By the way, this is not a forum, this is a place where one question gets answered.  Comments are to clarify an answer, not to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ----- TIMER 2 Sec. ------
removeAction(forKey: "Timer") // Timer delete
var time = 20                 // start counter

self.run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run {
    time -= 1
    print("\(time)")

     if time <= 0 {
         // start your code here!
     }

},SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1)]), count: time), withKey: "Timer")
```